# Add strings together in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, operator-keyword

i need to get a string in jQuery to determine an integer value, then add the letters "px" to the string.

So, this is what I have:

```
$(function(){
    var embed_height = $('.embedheight').height();
    if( embed_height < 160 )
    {
        var imheight = embed_height-10;
        var infowidth = imheight+10+"px";                    
            $('.embedinfo').css('left','infow');
    }
});
```

what i need is the variable infowidth to say for example `135px`

currently, that jQuery function is not working

Comment: You can not assign a string to the CSS property `left`.

Comment: @Derek well, technically, you cannot assign anything _but_ a string to any css property, including `left`. But you're certainly right that 'infow' is not a valid `left`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why? jQuery will automatically cast units (px) on to an integer:

```
var infowidth = imheight+10;
$('.embedinfo').css('left', infowidth);
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rjzaworski/QF3Bn/) to play with it.

Comment: Also, note that the variable does need to be `infowidth`--not the string literal `'infow'` given in your example. :^)

Comment: yeah sorry the mix up there of `infow `is from a mistake before, although i tried it without the px added, and it wasnt working, ill try again

Comment: yeah that doesnt seem to be working, it works if i use `.css('left','35px');` however

Comment: Check the fiddle? I cut and pasted, and it seems to be working over there (in Chrome, at least..)

Comment: after a little bit of dicking around it seems to work if i put it before a few `.hide()` functions i had, for whatever reason :s but its working!